# Add clickable textview to table layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Add clickable textview to table layout dynamically

```
TextView Delete = new TextView(this);
Delete.setText("Delete");
Delete.setClickable(true);
Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TransDelete(ac);
    }
});
```

This is my row added dynamically.

```
public void TransDelete(final String TransID) {
    class TransDeleteClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);
            Toast.makeText(ViewTransactions.this, httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Sending Trans id.
            hashMap.put("TransID", params[0]);
            finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpUrlDeleteRecord);

            return finalResult;
        }
    }

    TransDeleteClass TransDeleteClass = new TransDeleteClass();
    TransDeleteClass.execute(TransID);
}
```

This is my onclick function. I tried to click my textview while launching the mulator but the textview does not respond to onclick . I have seen other forums but as I need to pass in my TransID which is not the id i show on screen. For example , I tried filtering the data and although the screen shows numbers added in numeric order, it is not the case for the database i am using.

Edit:

```
 <ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1,1,1"
            android:id="@+id/maintable" >

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

This is my xml page but the table pops up perfectly.
I have chosen to add my headers of the table layout dynamically too.

```
void addHeader(){
    /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
    tr = new TableRow(this);

    /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
    label = new TextView(this);
    label.setText("ID");
    label.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    label.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.addView(label,params);
    tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.
```

Just a part of my header of the table as adding more codes would require more description.

[image]

Comment: Have you added `android:clickable="true"` to your TextView?

Comment: setOnClickListener sets your view as clickable internally

Comment: how are you appending the texview to the table ?

Answer (score 0):

`final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N];` // create an empty array;

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // create a new textview
    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

    // set some properties of rowTextView or something
    rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);

    // add the textview to the tablelayout
    yourtable.addView(rowTextView);

    // save a reference to the textview for later
    myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
}
```